# Apache Ignite: Need to pull data from Teradata and display in UI

Tags: teradata, ignite, data-caching

I am investigating Apache Ignite to pull data from Teradata and cache it so that I can use it to display in UI. Now, we are doing it using Cassandra but we want to move out of it for some reasons. It will be helpful if I get few templates on how it can be achieved as I am not finding relevant code sources or docs to read through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the documentation page about loading the data into Apache Ignite: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/data-loading

Comment: Thanks for the reply Valentin. Every example here shows data pull from ignite cache or simple cache add. I need to know the most efficient way to load large data queried from teradata to cache. Also, should I add it in tabular format or can I add JSON data to cache? Any help here is appreciated.

Comment: @Chevy, no, these example show two ways of bulk-loading large datasets into Ignite. Ignite is abstracted from the data source meaning that it's up to you to implement logic that queries the source and maps the rows to key-value pairs that are stored in Ignite. If Teradata has a JDBC driver, you can also use Automatic Persistence feature [https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/automatic-persistence] that will automate this task.

Comment: I found 2 ways to load data into cache - one by using cache.put() method and other by using query. Can you explain me what is the real difference between these 2 ways of loading data and how it will affect my data read?

Comment: @Chevy Can you please clarify what you mean by loading "using query"? Are you referring to `CacheStore` approach? Note that `cache.put()` is usually not suitable for loading large amounts of data, because each operation is a synchronous distributed call. It's better to use `IgniteDataStreamer` instead, it will automatically batch the data. Data read does not depend on how you load the data.

Comment: My requirement is like this - I have some 60,000 rows fetched using SQL and I need to load it to cache. What is the best way to do it and config changes that I must include while running the node? Also, about "Using query" -> I saw some example where they are adding data to cache using SQL statements and I think it is basically if we use H2 server for L2 caching. Can you provide insight on this too?

Comment: There are two good ways - through the `CacheStore` and `IgniteDataStreamer`, both described in the 'Data Loading' documentation page (the link is in the response). I recommend to try both and check which gives better performance for your case.